Does compressing indexes reduce the size of already compressed backups?
I use backup compression everywhere. Recently, I discovered that my backups were getting a little too big. I decided to fix this by compressing the indexes in the database (typically PAGE compression). The database got much smaller. But to my surprise, the full backups didn't get smaller!
Is this expected behaviour?

LOB pages are never compressed, so might still help for those. Also the database header, GAM, SGAM etc.

Generally, compressing the same thing twice does not yield much savings in space used.
Compression works by replacing the repeating patterns by some shorter representation. And there is only limited number of times you can do this, until you have no repeating patterns left.

Apparently, columnstore compression makes backups smaller.
